# Excel: How to merge tables (some columns are different)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have some (tens) tables in Excel in this format:

```
Table1                  Table2                         Table3                  Table4
+------+------+------+  +------+------+------+------+  +------+------+------+  +------+------+------+------+
|  A   |  B   |  C   |  |  A   |  B   |  C   |  D   |  |  A   |  C   |  B   |  |  A   |  B   |  C   |  E   |
+------+------+------+  +------+------+------+------+  +------+------+------+  +------+------+------+------+
| datA | datB | datC |  | datA | datB | datC | datD |  | datA | datC | datB |  | datA | datB | datC | datE |
| datA | datB | datC |  | datA | datB | datC | datD |  | datA | datC | datB |  | datA | datB | datC | datE |
| datA | datB | datC |  | datA | datB | datC | datD |  | datA | datC | datB |  +------+------+------+------+
| datA | datB | datC |  | datA | datB | datC | datD |  | datA | datC | datB |
+------+------+------+  | datA | datB | datC | datD |  +------+------+------+
                        | datA | datB | datC | datD |
                        +------+------+------+------+
```

And want to join them to one big table.

```
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Source |  A   |  B   |  C   |  D   |  E   |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
| Table1 | datA | datB | datC |      |      |
| Table1 | datA | datB | datC |      |      |
| Table1 | datA | datB | datC |      |      |
| Table1 | datA | datB | datC |      |      |
| Table2 | datA | datB | datC | datD |      |
| Table2 | datA | datB | datC | datD |      |
| Table2 | datA | datB | datC | datD |      |
| Table2 | datA | datB | datC | datD |      |
| Table2 | datA | datB | datC | datD |      |
| Table2 | datA | datB | datC | datD |      |
| Table3 | datA | datB | datC |      |      |
| Table3 | datA | datB | datC |      |      |
| Table3 | datA | datB | datC |      |      |
| Table3 | datA | datB | datC |      |      |
| Table4 | datA | datB | datC |      | datE |
| Table4 | datA | datB | datC |      | datE |
+--------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

All these tables are "[Named tables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/overview-of-excel-tables-7ab0bb7d-3a9e-4b56-a3c9-6c94334e492c)". I think about [Power Querry](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/introduction-to-microsoft-power-query-for-excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605?ui=en-us&rs=en-us&ad=us), but don't have idea howto do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my dummy data:

[image]

Follow this process for each table to create a simple query:

1. Put your cursor anywhere in the table
2. Use Data>Get & Transform Data>From Table/Range
3. In the Power Query Editor, use Home>Close & Load

When you've done that, do this:

1. Use Data>Get & Transform Data>Get Data>Combine Queries>Append:

[image]

2. Select "Three or more tables" then add the queries you created above to the "Tables to append" box by clicking "Add>>"

[image]

3. Click OK on the Append dialog
4. Use Home>Close & Load in the Power Query Editor
5. Review your results

[image]

Note that columns with the same name have been stacked on top of each other. Columns with unique names have not.

Comment: Thanks for answer. In my Excel 2013 with [Power Query add-in](https://www.microsoft.com/cs-cz/download/details.aspx?id=39379) installed is this function available in `Power Query` tab > `Combine` section. (Names could be a little different, I have non-english version).